# How to extract timestamp differences in hours and do cumulative sum

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id            NUMBER(10),
    due_dt        TIMESTAMP(6),
    status        VARCHAR2(10),
    created_on    TIMESTAMP(6),
    act_taken_on  TIMESTAMP(6)
);

insert into test values(1,'21-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM','created','19-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM','20-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM');
insert into test values(1,'21-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM','created','20-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM','21-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM');
insert into test values(2,'21-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM','Approved','21-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM','22-SEP-22 02.53.10.016537 AM');

DB Version: Oracle SQL Developer 18c
```

I have one table from which I need to calculate the difference between the timestamp and need to show only the hours differences. As per the below explanation:

Need to populate below columns:

`aging` : When status is created then take differences between `created_on` and `act_taken_on` and it should show only the hours differences. If the `id` is repeating then it should sum up with the previous value.
In my sample data set for the `id` 1 there are two rows so the for the first row `aging` column will be 24 hrs approx. and for the next `id` 1 it should sum up with the previous value which is 24 hrs and give the result as 48 hrs approx.

`time_left`: difference between `due_dt` and `sysdate` and should show differences only in hours.

My attempt:

```
SELECT id,
CASE
when status = 'created' then (created_on - act_taken_on)
when status = 'Approved' then (created_on - act_taken_on)
end aging,
(due_dt - sysdate) time_left
from test;
```

Expected output:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  Aging  | time_left |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 24Hours | 48hours   |
|  1 | 48Hours | 48Hours   |
|  2 | 24Hours | 48Hours   |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, which *casts* timestamps as `date` as you only need *rounded hours* and uses `sum` function in its analytic form.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id, created_on;

 ID DUE_DT                    STATUS     CREATED_ON                ACT_TAKEN_ON
--- ------------------------- ---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
  1 21.09.22 02:53:10,016537  created    19.09.22 02:53:10,016537  20.09.22 02:53:10,016537
  1 21.09.22 02:53:10,016537  created    20.09.22 02:53:10,016537  21.09.22 02:53:10,016537
  2 21.09.22 02:53:10,016537  Approved   21.09.22 02:53:10,016537  22.09.22 02:53:10,016537
```

Right now is

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
19.09.2022 13.17:07
```

Query:

```
SQL> select id,
  2         round (
  3            sum (
  4               (cast (act_taken_on as date) - cast (created_on as date)) * 24)
  5               over (partition by id order by created_on),
  6            0) aging,
  7         round ((cast (due_dt as date) - sysdate) * 24, 0) time_left
  8    from test;

 ID      AGING  TIME_LEFT
--- ---------- ----------
  1         24         38
  1         48         38
  2         24         38

SQL>
```

---

As you commented that you'd want to include `CASE` expression that regards the `status` column (but you're getting some errors), I'm not sure what exactly you meant to do with that, but - here's how (`time_left` has changed as `sysdate` now returns 20.09.2022 07:02):

```
SQL> select id,
  2         sum (
  3            case
  4               when status = 'created'
  5               then
  6                    (cast (act_taken_on as date) - cast (created_on as date))
  7                  * 24
  8               when status = 'Approved'
  9               then
 10                    (cast (act_taken_on as date) - cast (created_on as date))
 11                  * 24
 12            end)
 13            over (partition by id order by created_on) aging,
 14         round ((cast (due_dt as date) - sysdate) * 24, 0) time_left
 15    from test;

        ID      AGING  TIME_LEFT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         24         20
         1         48         20
         2         24         20

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but in my sample data I have 2 status i.e created and approved. But when I am writting analytic form in CASE expression it is throwing missing expression error

Comment: I know you have two statuses, but - according to code you wrote and no explanation regarding that column's value, I presumed that its value simply doesn't matter as you're subtracting CREATED_ON and ACT_TAKEN_ON in every case.

Comment: Sorry about that for not mentioning in the question but I need to use this case expression also but when I am adding I am getting error

Comment: See if code I posted helps in what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your TIMESTAMP values to DATEs, then subtract them and take the FLOOR (that is, round down).

When you subtract one DATE from another you get a floating-point value that's the difference between them in calendar days.

Like this:

```sql
FLOOR(24*(CAST(due_dt AS DATE) - CAST(created_on AS DATE)))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I will be able to calculate cumulative sum of aging column? And I tried with FLOOR and CAST for calculating aging column but it is giving 1 in the result set